# How can I prevent horizontal scrolling in an Android Cordova app?

Tags: android, cordova

With earlier versions of Cordova (pre 5.0, pre-4.0 android), I could prevent horizontal scrolling by doing the following:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    disablehorizontalScrolling();
    ....
}
private void disableHorizontalScrolling() {
    appView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    appView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
    appView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
}
```

After upgrading to Cordova 5.0 today, none of those methods are available anymore on CordovaWebView...

What is the modern replacement for the above?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer after poking around a bit.

`CordovaWebView` (now `CordovaWebViewImpl`) no longer extends WebView (or anything else).  The `WebView` object, itself, can now be accessed via `appView.getEngine().getView()`.

So, the modern replacement for the old code is

```
...
private void disableHorizontalScrolling() {
    WebView view = (WebView)appView.getEngine().getView();
    view.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    view.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
    view.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
}
```